# I get an error whenever I try to add myself to sudoers

Tags: linux, sudo

So I installed Debian yesterday, and I tried to make myself a sudoer so that I don't have to be root every time I try to install something. However, this always happens when I add my user to the sudo group.

```
gabe@GabePC:~$ sudo apt-get install steam
[sudo] password for gabe:
gabe is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
gabe@GabePC:~$ su -
Password:
root@GabePC:~# adduser gabe sudo
The user `gabe' is already a member of `sudo'.
root@GabePC:~#
```

Is there something else I have to change in order to make myself a sudoer?

Comment: How does your `/etc/sudoers` file look? (I don't use Debian, but I've got the `wheel`-group configured to have `sudo`-rights, not the `sudo`-group.)

Comment: I tried adding my username to the sudoers file by using visudo but that didn't work either

Comment: OK, but in what way? Does your `/etc/sudoers` resemble [this](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo)? Importantly, does it include the line `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`? That's what gives the `sudo`-group powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes will take effect as soon as you log out and log back in again. If you do that or simply reboot, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Ok, I haven't tried that yet so that is probably the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to execute commands as root, you have to be listed in the sudoers file. You should edit the sudoers-file with the visudo-command:

1. Edit the visudo-File as root : `visudo`
2. Navigate to the section `# User privilege specification` (Not really a section, but you should keep the layout..)
3. Hit the Letter 'i' to get into the INSERT-Mode
4. Add the followling line: `gabe  ALL=(ALL)   ALL` , DON'T remove/edit any other line !
5. Hit [ESC] to exit the INSERT-MODE and type `:wq`
6. Log out and log in again.

Comment: I tried doing that, but when I pressed esc nothing happened and it just added the ":wq" to the end of the ALL=(ALL) ALL line

Comment: Please remove the ":wq" at the end of the line. When you press 'i' there should be `-- INSERT --` in the bottom left corner and you will be able to edit the file. With the [ESC]-Key you should be able to leave the insert mode and the `-- INSERT --` should disappear . The command `:wq` writes the changes to the file and quits the editor.